# DateRangePicker plugin how can I filter the current quarter/last quarter, current year/last year in the?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

How can I filter the **current quarter** and **last quarter**, **current year** and **last year** in the DateRangePicker plugin? Is there any kind of built-in capability for such a filter? Or maybe some example of how to do this?

```
$('#dropdownMenuButton').daterangepicker({
ranges: {
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    'Current quarter'
    'Last quarter'
    'Current year':
    'Last year':
},
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quarter = moment().quarter();
var year = moment().year();

$('#dropdownMenuButton').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
    'Current Quarter': [moment().quarter(quarter).startOf('quarter'), moment().quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter')],
  'Last Quarter': [moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').startOf('quarter'), moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter')],
  'Current Year': [moment().year(year).startOf('year'), moment().year(year).endOf('year')],
  'Last Year': [moment().subtract(1, 'year').startOf('year'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year')]
        },
```